# Why does sqlite (read-only) work running in Docker locally but not in Google Cloud Run?

Tags: python, docker, sqlite, google-cloud-run

I have a substantial sqlite database file (~2 million rows) which I query in a Rust application using rusqlite on Google Cloud Run, using a bundled version of sqlite.

I do not add or write data, and open the database connection in read-only mode. Running the container in Docker locally, queries work perfectly. In Cloud Run, the database is successfully connected to, but attempting to prepare a query panics with "Error preparing search statement: SqliteFailure(Error { code: NotADatabase, extended_code: 26 }, Some("file is not a database"))".

This is a little bit mystifying because the database file has already been connected to!
I had a few hypotheses:

1. Something to do with a shortage of memory or attempting to write to Cloud Run's read-only file system? However, running in Docker with 256mb of memory and read-only mode enabled still worked.
2. A syscall prevented by gvisor? Running strace in docker showed no problems though, and there are no unsupported syscall logs.

Any suggestions as to what might be happening?

EDIT: just to add to the mystery: I wrote a quick Flask application to do the same thing using Python's built in sqlite, and get the same error...

EDIT 2: Using a database with a single row instead of 2 million, everything works as expected.

The original database is around 435MB in size.

To have a minimally reproducible example, the Python version simply receives a request, opens a connection, and queries:

```
@app.route('/detail/<int:rowid>/', methods=["GET"])
def get_individual_address(rowid):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_NAME)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT 
                postcode,
                town_city_or_rural_location,
                suburb,
                line_one
            FROM addresses WHERE id = ?""", (rowid,))
    if result := cur.fetchone():
        conn.close()
        return {
            "postcode": result[0],
            "town_city_or_rural_location": result[1],
            "suburb": result[2],
            "line_one": result[3]
        }
    else:
        conn.close()
        abort(404)
```

Similarly a simplified Dockerfile which still reproduces the problem is below:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080
WORKDIR /app
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT address_lookup:app --workers 1 --threads 1 --timeout 60
```

Comment: How large is the database file? Did you try deploying with more memory? The error message might indicate that the database file is corrupt. Show your Dockerfile and deployment command.

Comment: Can you show how you start your SQLite database?

Comment: @JohnHanley Example Dockerfile added, have tried with 2GB of RAM and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere You can reproduce the problem as above, it still recurs connecting with a URI to ensure immutability as well (e.g. sqlite3.connect("file:[db_name]?mode=ro&immutable=1&nolock=1", uri=True)

Comment: Does it fail at connect or when you run a query? Did you try with much more memory? 8Gb for example?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to the user which runs the container? Maybe the .sqlite file is not accessible by the user which runs the container in the cloud.